# Can I add a compound unique key if one of the fields is already unique

Tags: mysql, schema, unique-constraint, unique-key, unique-index

In MySQL, does following statement make sense?

```
CREATE TABLE `sku_classification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sku` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `business_classification_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_SKU_BUSINESS_CLASSIFICATION` (`sku`,`business_classification_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sku` (`sku`)
)
```

Is it an unnecessary overkill to add a unique key on a combination of fields (`sku`,`business_classification_id`), one of which (`sku`) already has unique index on it? Or is it not, and there is indeed some reason for such duplicate unique index?

Comment: Why would you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: @juergen-d legacy code. contemplating whether I should remove it.

Comment: The first unique key by itself would allow multiple same sku's  with different classifications. The second would prevent multiple rows with the same sku, so it makes the first one irrelevant. The real question is what is really needed. Is it OK to have the same sku with different classifications, or can there only be one row with a particular sku. IOW, what is the desired business logic?

Comment: @SloanThrasher sku should be unique. So I guess composite key does not make any difference and should be removed.

Comment: Yep. It would never come into play since only one row would be allowed for an sku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  But it does not make sense.  But, let's analyze what is going on.

An `INDEX` (`UNIQUE` or not) is a BTree that facilitates lookups in the table.

A `UNIQUE` index is both an index and a "constraint" saying that *there shall not be any duplicates*.

You have already said `UNIQUE(sku)`.  This provides both an index an a uniqueness constraint.

Adding `UNIQUE(sku, x)` *in that order*:

- Does not provide any additional uniqueness constraint,
- Does not provide any additional indexing capability, *except*...
- Does provide a "covering" index that could be useful *if* the only two columns mentioned in a `SELECT` were `sku` and `x`.  Even so, you may as make it an `INDEX` not a `UNIQUE`, *because*...
- Every `INSERT` must do some extra effort to prevent "duplicate key".  (OK, the `INSERT` code is not smart enough to see that you have `UNIQUE(sku)`.)

If that is your complete table, there is *no* good reason to have the `id AUTO_INCREMENT`; you may as well promote `sku` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (A PK is a `UNIQUE KEY`.)

Furthermore...  If, on the other hand, you were suggesting `UNIQUE(x, sku)`, then there is one slight difference.  This provides you a way to efficiently lookup by `x` -- a range of `x`, or `x=constant AND sku BETWEEN ...`, or certain other thing that are not provided by `(sku, x)`.  *Order matters in an index*.  But, again, it may as well be `INDEX(x, sku)`, not `UNIQUE`.

So, the optimal set of indexes for the table *as presented* is not 3 indexes, but 1:

```
PRIMARY KEY(sku)
```

One more note:  With InnoDB, the PK is "clustered" in BTree with the data.  That is, looking up by the PK is very efficient.  When you need to go through a "secondary index", there are two steps: first drill down the secondary index's BTree to find the PK, *then* drill down the PK's BTree.